# Did Trump ever state his opinion of Theodore Roosevelt?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, theodore-roosevelt

An [earlier answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/12922/115) pointed to the fact that Trump, seemingly, thinks America was great under President [Theodore Roosevelt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_Roosevelt). Did Trump ever state his opinion of Theodore Roosevelt? Both as a personality, as well as Roosevelt's complicated and nuanced views?

---

<sub>Ironically, I just finished listening to a a neat "History on Fire" podcast about Theodore Roosevelt, which highlighted just how nuanced his views were, on pretty much every conceivable topic.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible to prove a negative, but it does not appear that, as of this writing, Donald Trump has ever said anything publicly about Theodore Roosevelt.

There are [dozens](http://www.commdiginews.com/politics-2/is-donald-trump-channeling-president-theodore-roosevelt-48488/) [of](http://foreignpolicy.com/2015/09/09/is-donald-trump-the-heir-to-teddy-roosevelts-legacy/) [articles](http://www.newsmax.com/Newsfront/teddy-roosevelt-donald-trump/2016/08/28/id/745522/) [comparing](http://www.forbes.com/sites/realspin/2015/12/15/donald-trump-teddy-roosevelt/) [Donald](http://www.forbes.com/sites/realspin/2015/12/15/donald-trump-teddy-roosevelt/) [Trump](http://www.wnd.com/2016/01/global-insider-trump-is-new-teddy-roosevelt/) [and](http://www.sandiegouniontribune.com/opinion/commentary/sdut-trump-president-roosevelt-2016feb24-story.html) [Theodore](http://www.dickmorris.com/trump-theodore-roosevelt-historical-metaphor/) [Roosevelt](http://www.newsday.com/news/nation/expert-teddy-roosevelt-s-gop-reforms-aided-donald-trump-1.12524558), and not one of them has mentioned Trump's general opinion of the 26th President. As the question you pointed to suggested, he seems to have indicated that that was a period when America was great, but has not elaborated further on the president himself. I figured if he had said anything, that would be a quote in several of these articles, but its absence suggests he has never publicly said anything.

Comment: There are also dozens of articles in Lexux-Nexus from prior to 2015 that mention both names. I skimmed through a lot of them but couldn't find any relevant remarks from Trump.

Comment: Agreed, but a recent discovery at the white house paints them as quite close.   https://www.advocate.com/politics/2018/10/15/donald-trump-drinks-lincoln-and-roosevelt-white-house-portrait